# OK, Close button not visible by default

Tags: button

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on HP Mini and most of the times the <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> buttons at the bottom are not visible. I have to maximize the windows to make them visible. How to change this?

Answer (score 1):

Holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and pressing the left mouse button allows you to drag the window around - while not perfect, this may help you to reach the buttons.

Comment: thnx - it works as a temp fix.